# Prove that the given set is a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

> Prove that if $d$ is a metric and $(X,d)$ is a metric space then                $D(x,y)=(d(x,y))^2$ is also a metric on $X$.

I have problem of showing that $D(x,y)$ is well-defined and proving the triangle inequality to prove that $D(x,y)$ is a metric on $X$.

Please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Thinking out loud a bit: $D(x,z)=(d(x,z))^2 \leq (d(x,y)+d(y,z))^2 = d(x,y)^2 + 2d(x,y) d(y,z) + d(y,z)^2 = D(x,y) + 2 d(x,y) d(y,z) + D(y,z)^2$. Can the inequality fail when the middle term is dropped?

Comment: Hmm this is true it holds  because the middle term is  positive so this is cleared now i just want to be sure about the well defining this metric

Comment: The problem is the other way around: it can happen that the middle term "saves" the inequality, and it would fail without this additional term. The examples in the answers demonstrate this point.

Comment: Yes i saw now that theoretically it changes nothing but as we find at least one example where the triangle inequality doesnt hold that means there something wrong

Comment: Also, typo earlier: at the end you get $D(x,z) \leq D(x,y)+D(y,z) + 2d(x,y)d(y,z)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assertion is false. Take an isosceles triangle with one angle equal to $120$ degrees. Then the sides are $1$, $1$, and $\sqrt{3}$. But $1^2+1^2\lt 3$.

Comment: Before the edit I was wondering if you had posted on the wrong page ;)

Comment: I decided that without "the assertion is false" the answer might be excessively mysterious.

Comment: you are awesome

Answer (score 3):

$d(x,y)=\vert x-y\vert$ then $D(1,4)\leq D(1,3)+D(3,4)$ wont be correct. since
$\vert 1-4\vert ^2=9> \vert 1-3\vert ^2+\vert 3-4\vert ^2=4+1=5$

Comment: triangle inequality is  convese, isnot it?

Comment: infact you have to have $\vert 1-4\vert ^2=9\leq \vert 1-3\vert ^2+\vert 3-4\vert ^2=4+1=5$ which isnot correct

Comment: Hmm so we found an example  for the metric d(x,y) for which the triangle inequality doesnt hold so does it imply that D(x,y) is not a metric since the third condition doesnt hold ?

Comment: you are quite right